# Delphi form without system menu but with close button

Tags: delphi

By default, a form having BorderStyle=bsSizeable has a system menu (on the left) and a close button ('X', on the right). I want to get rid of the system menu and keep the close button.

The BorderIcons property lets me remove the system menu (via biSystemmenu), but now the close button is gone too.

Is there a way to do this?

Using Delphi XE

PS: it should be possible as far as Windows is concerned: IE8's "InPrivate Filtering settings" window is sizeable, has a close button and has no system menu.

Comment: Strange, for me the default for `BorderStyle=bsDialog` does **not** have a system menu regardless of what is specified in `BorderIcons`. `biSystemMenu` needs to be there for the red X to show.

Comment: You're right, bsDialog does work the way I want. Blush ;-) I've updated the question: I want it to work for bsSizeable as well.

Comment: @Andreas - You mean custom draw a button?

Comment: I think you should be clear: What you're looking to get rid of is the *icon*, not the *menu*. Right-clicking the title bar always displays the menu, regardless of whether there's an icon in the upper left corner.

Comment: @Rob: Yes, that's a better way to say it

Comment: @Sertac: No, I just meant that WMC is another example of such a window (with close button, but without the system menu icon), besides the "InPrivate" window mentioned above).

Comment: OK, I forgot to state the obvious. When I talk about the WMC window (and its frame), I am - of course - talking about the window when it is windowed and has a normal window frame, and hence not when it is in full-screen mode.

Comment: @Giel As an aside, such a window would be very annoying to me! I've just looked at WMC on @Andreas's suggestion. I often close a window by double clicking its caption bar icon. This is no longer possible if the icon is removed! Firefox and Chrome are two apps that do this and I find it very frustrating.

Comment: @David: It's not the main window, and non-sizeable dialog-style windows don't have an icon anyway. FWIW: until today I didn't know you could doubleclick the icon or rightclick the title bar ;-)

Comment: @Giel It wouldn't bother me whether or not it was the main window. I'd be itching to double click up there! Regarding windows dialog style windows, they'd usually respond to ESC or ENTER. It's always worth trying to stick to the tried and tested UI idioms because you may not be aware of the nooks and crannies. I thought I knew lots about this subject but I didn't know about right click caption bar either until today!!!

Comment: That Delphi3000 link is dead - do you mind posting the working code?

Answer (score 1):

`BorderStyle := bsSizeToolWin` does what you want, with a slightly different appearance of the X button.

Comment: -1. This is too different, and this unwanted difference is not necessary.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Who is the author of this unwanted difference? Did Microsoft want to make a difference between "normal windows" and "tool windows"?

Comment: @user1580348: Correct. Tool windows have smaller borders, and that's very intentional: small, floating, stay-on-top windows shouldn't have massive borders. Here's an example from Microsoft Word 1997: [Screenshot](https://privat.rejbrand.se/WordToolWnds.png). Word and the About dialog have thick title bars, but the Office Assistant and the floating drawing toolbar -- which are tool windows -- have smaller title bars.

Answer (score 1):

By "system menu" do you mean icon on the left of title bar? Or popup menu invoked via right click?

If it is icon that you want to remove - use this code:

```
const
  WM_ResetIcon = WM_APP - 1;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  protected
    procedure WMResetIcon(var Message: TMessage); message WM_ResetIcon;
  end;

implementation

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PostMessage(Handle, WM_ResetIcon, 0, 0);
end;

procedure TForm1.WMResetIcon(var Message: TMessage);
const
  ICON_SMALL = 0;
  ICON_BIG   = 1;
begin
  DestroyIcon(SendMessage(Handle, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, 0));
  DestroyIcon(SendMessage(Handle, WM_SETICON, ICON_SMALL, 0));
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do this without resorting to custom drawing your non-client area which is very difficult when glass is involved.

Consider this method.

```
procedure TMyForm.DeleteSystemMenu;
var
  SystemMenu: HMenu;
begin
  SystemMenu := GetSystemMenu(Handle, False);
  DeleteMenu(SystemMenu, SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
end;
```

Yes it succeeds in getting rid of the close item from the system menu, but it also results in the close button being disabled. So it would seem that you can't have one without the other.

Comment: That appears to do the *opposite* of what's requested. It obviously keeps the system menu (since you're modifying it), but it disables the button.

Comment: Same thing for `DeleteMenu(SystemMenu, SC_SIZE, MF_BYCOMMAND);`It removes the Size menu item and as a consequence you can not resize the form.

Comment: @Rob Read my answer again. The point I'm making is that if you get rid of parts of the system menu, then the matching functionality on the caption bar is also disabled. In fact, you comment to the Q seems to be making a similar point.

Comment: But surely Windows Media Center doesn't do custom drawing of the frame? Yet it is resizable, have the minimize, maximize, and close buttons to the right, and has a normal system menu, but doesn't show the system menu icon to the far left.

Comment: @Andreas The accepted solution shows how to do what you describe. The original question wanted to get rid of the system menu and I believe that you can't do this and keep a functioning close button. As Rob pointed out though, you can get rid of the icon, keep the system menu, it still appears on ALT+SPACE, caption bar right click etc.